# How to find and replace a group while keeping the word

Tags: regular-expression

How using vim serach and replace change

```
title: <Translation {...messages.title} />,
title: <Translation {...messages.header} />,
title: <Translation {...messages.message} />,
```

into

```
title: <Translation id="key.subkey.title" />,
title: <Translation id="key.subkey.header"  />,
title: <Translation id="key.subkey.message"  />,
```

I've thought about something like:
`%s/{...messages\.[a-zA-Z ]*\}/id="\1"/g`
But I don't know how to make `[a-zA-Z ]*\` a reference to be used to paste in the new form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't know how to make `[a-zA-Z]*` a reference to be used to paste in the new form

Just put it inside `\(` and `\)`, that way you can refer to it in the replacement as `\1` (assuming that's the first group inside parentheses.)

```
%s/{\.\.\.messages\.\([a-zA-Z]*\)}/id="key.subkey.\1"/
```

See also [`:help s/\1`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#s%2F%5C1).